# What does “two-bit (jerk)” mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

From subtitles for a Russian movie. 
The source translated for two-bit was:

> полный/последний/конченный

[English meaning *totally, absolutely* (something bad)] (Do you know russian word "dno"?)

Comment: "Two bits" is an American expression for a quarter (dollar). Hence "Two-bit" is a slang adjective meaning "of little value". It doesn't appear to be a literal translation, but expresses a judgment which is presumably elsewhere in the script, or in the setting.

Comment: "Two-bit" is American slang for a quarter of a dollar. By extension, it means something cheap. A "two-bit jerk" would be a petty, unpleasant person.

Comment: @ColinFine You beat me by a few seconds...

Comment: If you are interested in a more accurate translation, 'two-bit' doesn't seem to correspond to the original Russian. The more appropriate English would be 'total (or absolute) jerk', meaning literally that the person is all jerk. A 'two-bit' jerk would be a jerk that is of little value or negligible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Two-bit" is an idiom meaning [*cheap* or *petty*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-bit). It comes from a slang term for the American [eighth of a dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_(money)), a "bit." Even after the "bit" was phased out of the currency in 1792, the term "two-bit" persisted to refer to the quarter dollar.

A *two-bit* person isn't worth much. From the Oxford English Dictionary under "two, adj, n., and adv.":

> 1978   T. Willis Buckingham Palace Connection viii. 155   Some other **two-bit General** will try shooting us up.

When applied to people or things, unless it is used ironically, it is a put-down or insult, implying cheapness or low quality.

So "two-bit jerk" may mean that the character isn't of much importance *and* he's a jerk (i.e. he's rude or crass).

Comment: Side note: the British equivalent of "two-bit" is the derogatory [**tuppenny-ha’penny**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuppenny-ha%27penny), an abbreviation of "two-and-a-half pence." *You’d think he’d lost a Rolex rather than that tuppenny-ha’penny old watch of his.* It's not heard much these days.

Comment: @WeatherVane Brits abbreviate "two-and-a-half-pence" with a phrase that's longer?

Comment: @DavidRice that is what it means. "Tuppence ha'penny" is a corruption of, and shorter than, "two pennies and a half penny". I didn't invent it, but it rolls more easily off the tongue.

Comment: Also because tuppeny-ha'penny is pronounced with four syllables, not six. (tup-nee hape-nee)

Comment: @WeatherVane: In what currency would 2.5 pence have been a meaningful amount?  In pre-decimal currency, a penny (1d) was 1/12 shilling.  In decimal currency, a new pence is 1/5 shilling, so 2.5p would be half a shilling, but I'm unaware of there ever having been any decimal ha'pennies.

Comment: pre-decimal there were smaller coins than the penny,  ie: ha'penny and farthing

Comment: @supercat, there was a time when low-skilled working people measured their annual income in single-digit pounds ([some examples here](http://www.pascalbonenfant.com/18c/wages.html)). The difference between 2 and 2.5 pence would have been significant then.

Comment: @supercat Decimal half pence were in circulation up till 1984.

Comment: @supercat the amount wasn't 2.5p but the older 2.5d from pre-decimal £sd currency when a farthing (a quarter penny) was the smallest coin, and 2.5d was meaningful because it was **10 farthings**.

Comment: ... and you might ask the same question about the relevance of 12.5 cents.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Dollars were historically divided into eights, a practice which continued for stock prices until fairly recently.  Ten farthings seems like a logical amount, but a list of historical British coinage shows 2d (tuppence) and 3d (quarter-shilling) coins, with nothing in between.

Comment: @supercat the old pounds were also divided into eighths, the half-crown (2s 6d) being one eighth. The small coins (less than 1s) were 6d, 3d, 1d, ½d and ¼d (farthing) but there was no 2 pence coin before decimalisation, after which the small coins were 5p, 2p, 1p, ½p. I don't know the source of the phrase tuppenny-ha’penny but a similar contraction was **three-ha’pence** which meant 1½d.

Comment: @WeatherVane There _were_ [pre-decimal 2d coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twopence_(British_pre-decimal_coin)), but only briefly for normal use. There was the "cartwheel" 2d in copper which circulated for a few years from 1797, but being 2oz of copper, was hardly "small change"! This was followed by a small silver 2d coin, minted in 1817,8 and 1820.  A 2d coin did continue (alongside 1d, 3d and 4d counterparts) but only as part of [Maundy Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Maundy#Maundy_coinage) issued by the sovereign on the Thursday before Easter.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Does the term "tuppence" stem from those obscure coins, or from convenience in speaking?  Tuppence would be 1/6 of a shilling, and "Three-ha'pence" would be 1/8 of a shilling.  If an item cost 2.5d, one could buy a whole number per pound (96 of them), but not per shilling.  One could buy a whole number (twelve of them) per half-crown, and that appears to have coexisted alongside the shilling and florin for quite some time, so maybe that's there the term originated?

Comment: @supercat just from colloquialism, I think, in the same way that "pennies" were called  "pence" and "three pennies" was "thruppence". After decimalisation people were saying "five new pennies" and it was some years before it became comfortable to revert to the older "fivepence". The 12-based currency was convenient to divide into different fractions, more so than decimal currency.

Comment: @TripeHound oh, that's interesting. I was speaking only from memory having been raised with, and gone through school using £sd.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was part-way through infant school when it changed ("D-Day"... Monday 15th February 1971 ... the day/date always stuck for some reason) so had some experience of using £sd (farthings had gone by that time, but blackjacks/fruit salads were effectively a farthing each; two for a ha'penny).The knowledge above came from a mild interest in coin-collecting.

Comment: @TripeHound in which case I will mention for supercat's benefit that the 3d *coin* was a twelve-sided thing called a *thruppenny **bit***. I believe *pins* were used for very small change at one time, hence the expression "for two pins I would..."

Comment: @WeatherVane At the risk of derailing the conversation even more: between 1937 and 1941 (in the UK) there were actually _three_ distinct legal-tender [3d coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threepence_(British_coin)#Brass_vs_silver_threepences). As well as the newly-introduced 12-sided brass coin you mention, there was the tail-end of the old "silver" 3d coins ("Joeys") as well as the silver Maundy version (which, since 1927, had a different design to the circulating version).

Comment: @DJClayworth Ah, interesting - I was pronouncing it in my head as "tu-pen-nee-ha-pen-nee"

Comment: @TripeHound there have been numerous different coins in circulation: as I said, I wrote about the currency at the time I was using it and it became obsolete.